# How can I open a help file in Vim on a new buffer in an existing window?

Tags: vim, window, buffer

I often take a look at help files in Vim, but sometimes I want to read one in full screen. Since the :help command opens it in a new window, and closing the old window, if it was the only one besides of the help file, for some reason closes Vim, the only way I found of doing this was opening the help file, and then reopening it in a new tab.

I wondered, is there any way to make the :help command (or another command) to open a help file in the same window, but a new buffer?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You might be looking for `:only` or `CTRL-W o` (the same command).  This makes the current window the only one on the screen.  All other windows are closed.

You can also vertically split the help window with:

```
:vert help {subject}
```

BTW, `:help` actually does open in a new buffer, it's just "unlisted".  To list all buffers, including the unlisted ones:

```
:buffers!
```

Answer (score 23):

If I understand the question correctly, all you need to do is to chain the *help* command call with the *only* command:

```
:help <subject> | only
```

Comment: is there a way to make it the default behavior, so that one does not always have to "|only" it

Answer (score 11):

The `:help` will usually open a new window *unless* the active window's buffer `buftype` is already `help`. So to truly reuse a window you must open a new empty buffer in that window with `:enew`, change the `buftype` with `:set buftype=help` and then issue the `:help <whatever>`.

For convenience you could define a command to do that in your `.vimrc`:

```
command! -nargs=1 -complete=help H :enew | :set buftype=help | :h <args>
```

And then use `:H {subject}` from any window.

Using this method you truly reuse the window and that allows you to use `C-^` to go to the alternate for example. It will also respect your window layout (split windows, etc) unlike the other answers.

Comment: In order for `C-^` to work you need to add `keepalt` before `:h <args` like this: `command! -nargs=1 -complete=help H :enew | :set buftype=help | :keepalt h <args>`

Answer (score 8):

You can open a new tab for help with `:tab help`. This will give you a full screen help. Also look at `:help :tab`.

Comment: Another option is as after-thought, open current window in new tab, `Ctrl-W T`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:help` to open the help window, then <kbd>Ctrl+W</kbd><kbd>_</kbd> to make that window full screen (mostly, see the `winminheight` option).

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that you could set winminheight=0 for hiding a Window!

While its a great trick, there will *still* be a little bar with the title of the old window, thats why my question was about opening a new buffer :P

Answer (score 2):

To open full size new tab with your desired topic:

```
:tab help {subject}
:tab h {subject}
```

Subject is any valid `:help` argument.

To split the current window:

```
:vert help {subject}
:vert h {subject}
```

Answer (score 2):

A more general variant of @Shamaoke's answer is to open the main help menu in a full window.

```
:help | only
```

Comment: 10 years after posting this question I'm still learning from its answers. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! This was a new thing for me too and really useful.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a custom command using capital H like so (works exactly like :h except that it uses the whole window):

```
command! -nargs=1 -complete=help H call HelpFullScreen( <f-args> )

function! HelpFullScreen( topic )
    exe "h " . a:topic
    wincmd j
    try
        clo
    catch /^Vim(\a\+):E444:/ " can't close last window
    endtry
endfunction
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

To make `:help | only` the default behavior, you can use autocmd:

```
autocmd FileType help wincmd o
```

or in lua:

```
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(
    "FileType", {
        pattern = {"help"},
        command = "wincmd o",
    }
)
```